# Is it possible to use svg animated on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg, dart

I have an animated SVG file. I tried with those packages. but it' doesn't work. Is there any way to use SVG animated file in Flutter?

[lottie_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie_flutter#-example-tab-)

[fluttie](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttie#-example-tab-)

[flare_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter#-installing-tab-)

Comment: Did you find any alternative?

Comment: @DaniGarcia No, I created lottie animation for my application. https://lottiefiles.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try
https://pub.dev/packages/drawing_animation

I always use it in my projects

You can use this as infinity loop:

```
AnimatedDrawing.svg(
 "assets/my_drawing.svg",
 run: true,
 duration: new Duration(seconds: 3),
 )
```

Or this one with you own loop logic:

```
 AnimatedDrawing.svg(
   "assets/my_drawing.svg",
   run: this.run,
   duration: new Duration(seconds: 3),
   onFinish: () => setState(() {
    this.run  = false;
   }),
 )
```

Comment: It is best to include some code and explaination beside a link in your answers.

Comment: This not particularly explanatory and therefore not very helpful, sadly.

Comment: The example in pub.dev are good but the lib is not null-safe and is thus useless for now.